# Exporting whole HTML page into PDF or Excel Sheet, with all the scrolling functionalities working

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I am using `dc.js` charts to generate charts and data table. In addition for generating pdf file, I m using `jquery.PrintArea.js` which does the trick. The only problem is that my charts has a lot of data and are having horizontal scroll bars which allows them to fit into a page.

[image]

Now when I am trying to generate PDF out of this, which is giving me a screenshot of the page.

The thing I actually want is that PDF which is exported should have scroll bars and user can scroll over the chart as they do on HTML page.

Any suggestion are welcome. 
If Excel Sheets can do what I want I can use them as well in place of PDF file.

Comment: As you want to export Chart object only to excel file. How about doing this on server side instead of clientside, as you get rich support of creating the excel objects like OpenXml SDK. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx, or any 3rd part library

Comment: Its looks like a solution, I am taking a look at it and will be tryin to implement it.Thanks @Kris

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, it is not possible.

PDF simply does not support such feature. There is no graph function in PDF. You can only add an image of graph to it, but nothing more can be done to it. PDF are for making printable documents, and a scrollbar is meaningless on paper.

With excel, the XLSX format itself supports this feature, but it requires settings on some details. This，as far as I know, is not possible with Javascript or other backend code. [Here is a reference how to do it manually.](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1433-excel-add-scrollbar-to-chart.html) This settings should be too complicated at least with javascript / jquery alone.

Comment: Thanks @cytsunny, I did all the research to find the solution.Still I am hoping that there might be something from where I can start to make this thing possible. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you at least focus your research on excel. For PDF, it is the problem of PDF format itself. I am quite sure there will not be a solution in the coming future.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to export Chart object only to excel file. How about doing this on server side instead of clientside, as you get rich support of creating the excel objects like OpenXml SDK. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx, or any 3rd part library.

Here are more [code snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc820055.aspx), which will help in creating the document.